# Apache Jena Intro RDF: NoSuchMethodError getIfPresent()

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, apache-jena

I was attempting to follow the [basic tutorial](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html#ch-Introduction) for creating a basic RDF from Apache Jena's website.

```
String personURI = "http://somewhere/JohnSmith";
String fullName = "John Smith";

Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
Resource johnSmith = model.createResource(personURI);

johnSmith.addProperty(VCARD.FN, fullName);
```

I added the 3.0.1 Jena dependency to my pom.xml, ran the code only find that it output an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jena.atlas.lib.Cache.getIfPresent(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  at org.apache.jena.enhanced.EnhGraph.getNodeAs(EnhGraph.java:133)
  at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.IteratorFactory.asResource(IteratorFactory.java:71)
  at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.IteratorFactory.asResource(IteratorFactory.java:62)
  at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.getResource(ModelCom.java:888)
  at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.createResource(ModelCom.java:1338)
  at com.lymba.proposal.summarizer.core.rdf.TestRdf.testRdf(TestRdf.java:15)
  at com.lymba.proposal.summarizer.core.rdf.TestRdf.main(TestRdf.java:21)
```

Why would the basic example give me this output? It's copied straight from the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be a dependency related issue. Based on the [some information](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201508.mbox/%3CD1EA4450.521B9%25rvesse@dotnetrdf.org%3E) I found from the jena-users mailing list, it had to do with different versions of Jean being found in my classpath.

I checked the dependency hierarchy in Eclipse and found that another of my dependencies was bringing in Jean 2.13.0. I added a exclusion to my pom for the Jean 2.13.0 artifact, and the tutorial worked as expected.